# Sinon stubs not being used

Tags: node.js, mocha.js, sinon

I have a lambda function which is referencing a module define in another file.
Instead of having to get all the scenarios right in my tests I'd like to just have a stub of that module.
In app.js

```
var Service = require("./Services/Service");
let service = new Service(event.Environment);
        var regulatorResults = await service.GetModifiers(budgeted, irrelevant, variables);
```

Service is defined as follows:

```
function Service(environment) {
    async function GetModifiers(ids, irrelevant, things) {
//logic happens
}
    return { GetModifiers };
}
module.exports = Service;
```

I've tried many different iterations in my tests but where I feel closest is with this:

```
var assert = require('assert');
var sinon = require('sinon');
var service = require('../Services/Service');

describe('Calculator', function () {
before(function () {
        var service = sinon.createStubInstance(regulatorService);


        sinon.stub(service.prototype, "GetModifiers").callsFake(async function(IDs, thing, thing) {
            return IDs.map(id=> new { ID: id, Modifier: 1 });
        });
    });
```

When I run the actual tests, the results of that service are [], even if I code the stub to return a set value, and if I throw in a console.log, it doesn't get hit ever.
The tests fail with error `Error: Trying to stub property 'GetModifiers' of undefined`.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can `Service` be an actual class so that `GetModifiers` is an actual prototype method?  That would make it a lot easier to mock.